# boolean function call within if statement

Tags: c++

I am a bit confused regarding my program below. In my if statement, I am calling the boolean function twice. For the i, and j variable I spicked, the "else" statement should be executed as both function calls will yield true. But my "i" variable is not being modified (it outputs as 1001 instead of 1000), and I have no idea why. The j variable is being modified as expected. The first function call passes in "j" variable, and the second function call passes in "i" variable. Could someone explain why the "i" variable is not being modified?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int MINCOLOR = 0;
const int MAXCOLOR = 1000;

bool clipColor(int &amountColor);


int main()
{
    int i=1001;
    int j = 3333;
    int k;
    bool check;

    if (clipColor(j) == false && clipColor(i) == false)
    {
        check = false;
    }
    else 
    {
        check = true;
    }

    cout << i << " " << j << " " << check << " " << endl;
    return 0;
}


bool clipColor(int &amountColor)       
{
  if (amountColor > MAXCOLOR)
  {
    amountColor = MAXCOLOR;
    return true;
  }
  else if (amountColor < MINCOLOR)
  {
    amountColor = MINCOLOR;
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of how the `&&` and `||` operators work. For `&&`, if the first operand is false, then the second operand is never even evaluated. Therefore, the second function call is not made.

This is known as [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), and is a feature not only of C and C++, but of most programming languages.

If you explicitly want to evaluate both sides, then for `bool` returns, the single `&` operator arguably does what you want. By specification, it does bit-wise AND, but since `bool` values only use exactly one bit, the result should be exactly what you need.

By the way, `clipColor(j) == false` is the same as `!clipColor(j)`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we have a dupe for that question.

Comment: Is there any way to make it so the second function call is evaluated though?

Comment: Thanks guys. I just wanted to condense some code. I guess I need to perform the two function calls before the if statement and assign them to 2 separate variables and then check the 2 variables instead.

Comment: Thanks Dolda2000. I'll try that.

Comment: Is using the single "&" to do what I wanted to do considered bad practice? Since we usually don't see single ampersands in conditions.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it bad practice, but some people out there are weird and may. :)

Comment: ah Okay. It is for an assignment I am doing. I'll just comment it so no it doesn't jump out as weird.

Comment: Would an alternative way to do it be to introduce 2 new bool variables before the if statement and assign each evaluation to each bool variable. Then instead of checking the function calls as I did in the OP, I can just check the 2 bool variables? That's the only other way I can think of doing it.

Comment: That way would also work, certainly, but I would consider it needlessly verbose.

Comment: If you are checking if two (or more) conditions, then using a single `&` is exceedingly bad practice, because it semantically does something very different (albeit related) than a boolean comparison.   If you want both functions to be called regardless, store their return values in separate variables, and then test those.   Yes, it is more verbose, but it is also clearer what the intent is - without needing to resort to a comment.  At the least, the typing of a comment should be counted as overhead.

Comment: @Peter: I disagree. The `&` operation is very well-defined, and will under no circumstances not do what was intended. Seeing as how `bool` values are well-defined to use only one bit, it isn't even semantically different -- it *is* a boolean comparison. As for the code being less readable, I also disagree: needless verbosity takes up unnecessary bandwidth when reading code, making it harder to read. I can agree to disagree on the subject -- conventions are subjective -- but please don't present your opinions as objective truth.

Comment: You're the one who claimed that anyone who disagrees with you is weird, Dolda. Real world programmers regularly use `&&` to work with boolean expressions, and `&` for bitwise operations, and using one where the other is normally used is misleading, and therefore a source of hard-to-find bugs.  You are therefore encouraging a beginner to adopt a bad habit that will be rejected out-of-hand in most professional code reviews.  The fact that nm17 feels the need to add a comment to explain using `&` over `&&` to his tutor makes the content of that comment part of the "bandwidth".

Comment: @Peter: "*You're the one who claimed that anyone who disagrees with you is weird*" -- That was obviously tongue-in-cheek, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
if (clipColor(j) == false && clipColor(i) == false)
{
    check = false;
}
else 
{
    check = true;
}
```

The function `clipcolor(j)` is executing first and returning true.
As a result there is no need for `clipColor(i)` to execute because whatever value `clipColor(i)` returns, the condition `(clipColor(j) == false && clipColor(i) == false)` will always be false.